# Azure Api App connection string for EF not working

Tags: entity-framework, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have created one Web Api project and add entity framewok 6 in this.

and Create the API App in App service in azure portal and publish Web Api project in this app.

everything is working fine but when I removed the Connection string from Web.config file and set connection string in azure app

following this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/62b9fa9d-7a4a-4927-a702-3e1e834d5187/azure-web-sites-connection-string-for-ef-not-being-picked-up

is not working.

I have put this dummay connection sting in my web.config file

Please help me what I am doing wrong or there is another approach for API App in azure portal.

Comment: As I can see you use SQL Server, but in the question by the link the author choose the connection type *Custom*. Try *SQL Database* or *SQL Server* instead.

Answer (score 0):

Connection string in web config will have `&quot;` for escaped quotes. you need to change them to '' before adding to azure app services connection string